# can content script run on https page chrome extensions development

Tags: permissions, https, google-chrome-extension

i am developing a chrome extension, when i run content script on http page, it is ok. But i am confuse why it can't do on https page. Can content script run on https page. And my permissions id like that.
`"permissions": [
"http://*/*",
"https://*/*",
"tabs"
],`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In addition to including `https` in the `permissions` section of your manifest, you also need to include it in the `matches` section of the `content_scripts` section:

```
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
    "js": ["script.js"]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Content scripts work on https pages. There is probably some other issue.